# C# properties in Unity: set value behaving oddly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, properties

I'm trying to better understand the use of properties, in particular within Unity game engine.
What I have to do is very simple: there is a class called "Enemy" that, every time it is instanciated (i.e. spawned), must access to the class GameSession and increase the value of a counter field, "numSpawnedEnemies", that however I want to be accessible through the property "NumSpawnedEnemies".

Note: GameSession is a singleton (i.e only 1 instance exists), but I omitted the related code for simplicity.

```
    public class GameSession : MonoBehaviour
{
    int numSpawnedEnemies = 0;
    
    
    public int NumSpawnedEnemies
    {
        get
        {
            return numSpawnedEnemies;
        }
        set
        {
            Debug.Log("Value: " + value); // Just for debugging purpose
            numSpawnedEnemies += value;
        }
    }
}
```

In the Enemy class I then do this, in the Start() method (i.e. the method automatically prompted by Unity for each instance of the Enemy class):

```
    gameSession = FindObjectOfType<GameSession>();
    // Unity function searching for the instance of GameSession
    gameSession.NumSpawnedEnemies += 1;
```

The result, however, is not what I expected: in fact the counter "numSpawnedEnemies" gets increased every time x2 (i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64...), rather than +1. That because, as the debug.console function shows, the value of "value" is, actually, 1, 2, 4, etc.

Setting the value to 0 (after assigning its value to numSpawnedEnemies) in the set {} doesn't change anything, but even if it would, that wouldn't explain to me this behaviour (in fact I expect that it get reset every time I access the property).

If I simply put numSpawnedEnemies as public and increment this field from the Enemy class, it works fine.
The questions then are:

1. How comes that "value" keeps track of a previous value? (shouldn't it be "reset" every time I access the property from some point?)
2. If answer to question 1  is that it is a normal behaviour, why does it get increased by x2 each time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short solution like
@Pino De Francesco said

change statement in property from

```
numSpawnedEnemies += value;
```

to

```
numSpawnedEnemies = value;
```

**Explaination**

You can treat the property like 'Get' and 'Set' method depend on you implenment.
So your NumSpawnedEnemies be like

```
void NumSpawnedEnemies(int value){
   numSpawnedEnemies += value;
}

int NumSpawnedEnemies(){ return numSpawnedEnemies;}
```

then if you call NumSpawnedEnemies += 1
it equal you pass **numberSpanwedEnemies + 1** as value
to **NumSpawnedEnemies(int value)**

then final equation of your statement is

```
numberSpawnedEnemies = numberSpawnedEnemies + value
numberSpawnedEnemies = numberSpawnedEnemies + (numberSpawnedEnemies + 1)
```

that why your result is double each time you called

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was really trivial, beginner faults I guess. Thanks also for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 3):

You have += on both the property and the Enemy using it.

In the property replace

numSpawnedEnemies += value;

With

numSpawnedEnemies = value;